# Obtener el registro de los últimos 6 domingos de cada usuario MySQL

Tags: mysql, jquery, sql, mysql-workbench

Buen día, cuento con una tabla llamada wallets donde se almacena diariamente el registro de cada usuario durante los 7 días de la semana. **Necesito obtener únicamente del día domingo de las últimas 6 semanas de un usuario en específico**. Por ejemplo: Si el último registro del usuario 5510 es miércoles 23 de junio, debería devolverme los domingos 20, 13, 6,...

Mi tabla **wallets** cuenta con la columna **created_at** donde me servirá de punto inicial para obtener los días domingos pasados. Adjunto los detalles de mi tabla:

```
SELECT a.id, a.cuenta, a.nombre, a.bucketd, a.created_at
FROM  wallets a 
where cuenta = 5510
```

La salida es el siguiente:

[image: Registro diario del cliente 5510]

Mi MySQL está en su versión más reciente. Espero me haya dado a entender, espero puedan apoyarme.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Es decir, lo que quieres obtener son tu 6 últimos domingos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que la función `DAYOFWEEK()` de `MySQL` puede servir para tu propósito.

Según la [definición de w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_dayofweek.asp) podemos decir que:

> La función DAYOFWEEK() devuelve el índice del día de la semana para una fecha determinada (un número del 1 al 7).

> Nota: 1 = domingo, 2 = lunes, 3 = martes, 4 = miércoles, 5 = jueves, 6 = viernes, 7 = sábado.

Con esto en mente podemos construir tu query de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wallets`
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(`created_at`) = 1 
AND `cuenta` = 5510
ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
LIMIT 6
```

En el que seleccionamos **todos los registros** de la tabla **wallets** que cumplan con la condición de que el día de la semana sea igual a **1 (domingo)** y la cuenta sea la **5510**. Luego ordenamos por el campo de fecha **created_at** de manera descendente y establecemos un límite de **6 registros**.

Prueba y nos cuentas.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, amigo. Disculpa por responder días despues. Funcionó correctamente. En verdad se aprecia. Saludos!!